# Wille php copy() work for a person viewing the site who has the site which i'm copying from blocked?

Tags: php, proxy, copy, cron

Say I use php copy(), to get a file from a site.

And then a user who is using a proxy filtering service that has that site blocked, will the site still be able to copy that file for the user?

If not, would a cron job be able to?

And is the same for file_get_contents?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on the server, so it is the webserver, not the user, which requests that remote file.

So yes, you can copy a file from a server which a user themselves might not be able to reach directly.